I am working in wordpress issue with java script overlay
I am working in wordpress elemnetor. I have a requirement to achieve. On header i have a search button when click on it overlay open with search bar i am using ivory search in this
thats image of search option
[My html code for overlay thats code i have inside html widget](https://i.sstatic.net/7oqAy4eK.png)

code of java script
my requirement is when click on search bar overlay close and i got result on my web site but i am getting result inside overlay
please help me

Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. We need a [mcve] that we can cop & paste and run and see the same issue you are seeing. From that we can debug and eventually post an answer.
